# React native payment gateway without SDK

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, payment

I am doing an e-commerce application using react native. We need to integrate a payment gateway which doesn't seems to have an sdk for react native(ADCB). How should I approach to this problem?

Can I proceed with **Custom Tabs** ?
 If so, how can I close the custom tab after the payment has been done?

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/newsagepay/newtest.php?&customerSage='+isuerID+'&checkSage=1';

CustomTabs.openURL(url,{ toolbarColor: '#607D8B',enableUrlBarHiding: true, showPageTitle: true, enableDefaultShare: true, 
animations: ANIMATIONS_SLIDE}).then((launched: boolean) => {                                                        
    console.log(`Launched custom tabs: ${launched}`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to suggest you `<WebView />` and you can use a property of webView called `onNavigationStateChange={}` pass on a function to it. Monitor the URL of the `webview` and handle it according to success or failure.

**for example.**
suppose payment successes URL is http://payment.sucess

```
<WebView 
onNavigationStateChange={(webViewState)=>{
console.log(webViewState.url)
if(webViewState.url==="http://payment.sucess"){
//navigate or close webview
}}
javaScriptEnabled = {true}
domStorageEnabled = {true}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I checked, web view is deprecated. And the new webview doesn't have a onNavigationStateChange event.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi you have not read the docs properly , webview is now https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview , also the onNavigationStateChange event works on it ,see https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange

Comment: Yes. My mistake. I am accepting your answer. Upvoted as well.. Thank you very much

Comment: But is this approach secure? Why does everybody implements sdk? Android's webview has a list of insecurities

Comment: @MaxFratane Have you found a way to protect it?

Comment: @OliverD You can create your own bridge and use native sdk for iOS/ android in your project. this method has its own limitations.